# simplehtmldom - SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages

Tags: ssl, file-get-contents, simple-html-dom

I'm using `http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/` and `file_get_contents()` in my webApp. The `file_get_contents()` work fine on localhost. But when upload webApp on server(Windows server 2012 r2) i get this error. How to fix this error?

```
> Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in E:\cfnic.com\includes\class\PHP_Simple_HTML_DOM_Parser.php on line 75

Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in E:\cfnic.com\includes\class\PHP_Simple_HTML_DOM_Parser.php on line 75

Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.markafoni.com/kadin/): failed to open stream: operation failed in E:\cfnic.com\includes\class\PHP_Simple_HTML_DOM_Parser.php on line 75

Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on boolean in E:\cfnic.com\includes\theme\category.php on line 159
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have to set the environment variable SSL_CERT_FILE to the path of the PEM file of the ssl-certificate downloaded from the following link : http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem.

It took me a lot of time to figure this out.

For a detailed answer, you can have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34590842/cannot-install-composer-on-mac-os-x/34617315